# Switch between multiple frames using tkinter in python in side menubar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a side menubar and use multiple labels as click buttons. But when I execute the program, only one label is clicked and event is shown in mainarea. Other event doesn't work.

Please provide me with a useful solution. Here is the code I have written:

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import ttk
    root = Tk()
    def MainScreen(self):
      label4 = Label(mainarea,width=100,height=80,text="Prapti Computer 
      Solutions")
      label4.pack(expand=True,fill='both')

   def ClientData(self):
      label4 = Label(mainarea,width=100,height=80,text="Yo this is client data")
      label4.pack(expand=True,fill='both')

   def Report(self):
      label6 = Label(mainarea,width=100,height=80,text="Report is onnnnn!")
      label6.pack(expand=True,fill='both')

   # sidebar
   sidebar = Frame(root, width=400, bg='white', height=500,  borderwidth=2)
   sidebar.pack( fill='y', side='left', anchor='nw')

   #submenus
   label1 = Label( sidebar,width=45,height = 2 , text="HOME", relief=FLAT )
   label1.bind("<Button-1>",MainScreen)
   label1.grid(row=0)

   ttk.Separator(sidebar,orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(row=1, columnspan=5)

   label2 = Label( sidebar,width=45,height = 2 , text="CLIENT", relief=FLAT )
   label2.bind("<Button-1>",ClientData)
   label2.grid(row=2)

   ttk.Separator(sidebar,orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(row=3, columnspan=5)

   label3 = Label( sidebar,width=45,height = 2 , text="REPORT", relief=FLAT )
   label3.bind("<Button-1>",Report)
   label3.grid(row=4)

   # main content area
   mainarea = Frame(root, bg='#CCC', width=500, height=500)
   mainarea.pack(expand=True, fill='both', side='right')
   root.attributes('-alpha', 0.98)

   root.mainloop()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep packing things but you never remove them. You need to remove the current page before switching to the new page.

For example:

```
current_page = None

def MainScreen(self):
   global current_page
   if current_page is not None:
       current_page.pack_forget()
   label4 = Label(mainarea,width=100,height=80,text="Prapti Computer Solutions")
   label4.pack(expand=True,fill='both')
   current_page = label4
```